# C# Image resize- quality losing

Tags: c#-3.0

I have used a C# method to resize the image size.I have used several methods from the following links.

[C# Simple Image Resize : File Size Not Shrinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909523/c-sharp-simple-image-resize-file-size-not-)
shrinking

[Resize an Image C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp)

but quality is missing when re-sizing the image

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: one of possible duplicate seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87753/resizing-an-image-without-losing-any-quality

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Component) (Windows Imaging Component) instead of GDI+. Here's a [nice blog post](http://keyvan.io/image-resizing-with-windows-imaging-component-in-net) with an example.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your `Bitmap` to an `Image`

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap("asdf.jpg");
Image i = (Image)b;
```

then pass the image to this method to resize

```
public static Image ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height, bool onlyResizeIfWider)
{
    using (image)
    {
        // Prevent using images internal thumbnail.
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);

        if (onlyResizeIfWider == true)
            if (image.Width <= width)
                width = image.Width;

        // Resize with height instead?
        int newHeight = image.Height * width / image.Width;
        if (newHeight > height)
        {
            width = image.Width * height / image.Height;
            newHeight = height;
        }
        Image NewImage = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, newHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        return NewImage;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.